# Load SVG via JS function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load an SVG into div via a Javascript function, the div has been set as `<div class="svgicon"></div>`

I can change the div class if this was an image via the urlbackground, but having tried this for an SVG it fails to render

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

What is the error? You shouldn't have any problems with changing the class. Check out this example.

```js
function changeSVG() {
 var div = document.getElementById('foo');
 if ( div.className == "class1" ) {
    div.className = "class2";
  } else {
   div.className = "class1";
  }
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', changeSVG);
```

```css
.class1 {        
        background-image: url('https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg');
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
      }

      .class2 {
        background-image: url('https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/aa.svg');
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
      }
```

```html
  <div id="foo" class="class1">
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="btn" type="button" >
  Switch
  </button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, it seems that if you change a animated svg dynamically the animation does not play, you just get the initial state. I have seem a few articles here that describe the problem, is there any solutions?

Comment: Does it have something like 'begin="click"'? If so, you can try trigger the click programatically, or the event that starts the animation.